# How to remove low-correlated features to a target?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataset of 100+ columns from which I want to automatically remove low-correlated features compared to a target, so I can exclude zero-importance features.

I run Python 3.5 on Jupyter Notebook and already removed highly correlated co-features.

I've tried so far something like that:

```
corr = train.corr().abs()

columns = np.full((corr.shape[0],), True, dtype=bool)
for i in range(corr.shape[0]):
# Here I want compare a feature to my target
    if corr.iloc[i,'Target'] >= 0.2:
        if columns[i]:
            columns[i] = False

selected_columns = train.columns[columns]
train = train[selected_columns]
```

Help with the code would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: First, you remove features which are highly correlated with other features, e.g. a,b,c are highly correlated, just keep a and remove b and c. Then you can remove features which are low-correlated to your target variable in case that you are just interested in linear problems. What I see here, is that you removed features with intermediate and high correlation to your target variable. Why did you do that?

Comment: Yes, bad sign... I'm trying to select most relevant features based on Chi-square now.

Comment: Please let me understand what your goal is? What do you want to do with the data later? Do you know anything about the relationship between `X` and `y`?

Comment: The code above is perhaps bad example. I've used it to exclude highly correlated features. My goal is to remove zero importance and low correlated features compared to a target, so my dataset does not have some 100+ columns but way less.

Comment: By removing low correlations you'll get rid of higher order relations as well! For example if your target is perfectly related to the first column squared, then you'll remove the first column! A way to reduce your dimensionality is using PCA, another is to use random forest and feature importance.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about PCA... But I&#39;ve got some features like 0.05 on spearman and thought those are not really necessary. But PCA would probably solve the problem. Yes.

Comment: @anishtain4 Is feature importance intended only for gradient boosting models which does not (easily) work on Windows?

Comment: You can use sklearn random forest, it has the feature importance.

Comment: @anishtain4 OK, thanks.